# How to append a json line to a loaded json file?

Tags: python, json, append

I am writing Python code.
I loaded a json file.

```
with open('..\config_4099.json', "r") as fid:
    jaySon = json.load(fid)
```

It's a flat json structure, so no internal elements to append to. Just need to tack onto the bottom the piece in curlies:

```
jaySon.append({'pluginInputs': "PluginInputs"})
```

It's complaining about dictionaries.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by a "flat json structure". Please add a (small) example of what's in the loaded file to your question.

Comment: Flat just meant no layers.
{
  "formatVersion" : 1,
  "id" : 4099,
  "turbineType" : "string"
}

Comment: Then @MrGeek's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

With dicts, use [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
jaySon.update({'pluginInputs': "PluginInputs"})
```